# Is it possible to execute commands from array?

Tags: php

Just out of curiosity is it possible to do something like this:

```
$commands = [
    strtolower('JUST TESTING'),
    date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    strtoupper('Done!'),
];


foreach ($commands as $command) {
    $command;
}
```

This of course doesn't work! Is there a way to make it work?

---

My specific use case is something like this:

```
private function dropDatabasesAndMySQLUsers(): void
{
    foreach ($this->getCommands() as $command) {
        $command;
    }
    $this->info('Done! All app Databases and MySQL users are dropped');
}

public function getCommands(): array
{
    return [
        \DB::statement("DROP USER IF EXISTS 'myuser'@'localhost'"), 
        \DB::statement("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS manager")
        // I have about 20-30 of these
    ];
}
```

Comment: Please research more before asking so that Stack Overflow does not need to house redundant content.  This is a mega-duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to store a "command" in a way that is reusable and can be passed around is to use a **function**.

```
<?php

$commands = [
     function () { print 1+2; },
     function () { print 2+6; }
];

foreach ($commands as $command) {
    $command();
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve that is to use the functions names as string. `"strtolower"("FOO");` will provide the same output than `strtolower("FOO");` :

```
<?php
$commands = [
    "strtolower"    => 'JUST TESTING',
    "date"          => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    "strtoupper"    => 'Done!',
];

foreach ($commands as $functionName => $arg) {
    echo $functionName($arg) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This outputs :

```
just testing
2020-07-04 14:45:16
DONE!
```

Comment: I needed this for functions like this `\DB::statement("DROP USER IF EXISTS 'myuser'@'localhost'");` `\DB::statement("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS manager");` and I have about 20-30 of them so your solution is not appropriate for my case!

Comment: @lewis4u `\DB::$functionName()` works too

Comment: try to update your answer and add that to it... for others to see how would that look like with those 2 commands in my comment...

Comment: Update your question if you have a specific use case

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Are you only running `\DB::statement()` methods ?

Comment: In this one yes

Comment: Then store only the arguments in an array, loop over it and call `\DB::statement($arg)`